# How to get all the keys and and value from array list in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter-3

i want to know is there anyway to  get all the qids without using foreach loop .

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [position] => 2
            [qid] => 4
        )
```

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [position] => 2
        [qid] => 1
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [position] => 2
        [qid] => 1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [position] => 2
        [qid] => 5
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [position] => 2
        [qid] => 4
    )
```

)

Thanks.

Comment: Which language do you use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_map` function:

```
$qids = array_map(function ($item) {
    return $item['qid'];
}, $incomingArray);
```

If you need an unique qid values, use additional `array_unique` function call:

```
$qids = array_unique($qids);
```